# How to add a permanent custom format to Excel so it is selectable in any workbook I open

Tags: excel, date, format

I am trying to figure out how to get a particular date format to be permanently added to the Custom formats list.   Currently, I have to manually format to dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss.000.

I know I can make a macro to do this, but that seems to only exist in a single workbook and I am looking for it to work across any excel workbook I open up.

Comment: Do it in personal.xlsb?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a style in which you only save the number format.

[image]

You open an other workbook and import that style (all custom styles are importet):

[image],
[image]

Apply style

[image]

[image]

Or you adjust the template for all new workbooks. Or you create a new template.